# Dynamically setting the URL in a wicket link

Tags: dynamic, properties, wicket

I have hard-coded the link destination URL in the below link.

```
<a href="+https://accent.com+" target="_parent"></a>
```

I need to re-factor the  code so that the URL is set dynamically (reading it from a property file) Any one has an idea how to achieve that in wicket? 

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ExternalLink` in your Java code. Its model can read/load it from anywhere you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without the need for any Java code.

Given a properties file with a key for the url and the links label:

```
url = http://www.stackoverflow.com
label = Help me!
```

One can simple use Wicket message system:

```
<a wicket:message="href:url"><wicket:message key="label" /></a>
```

Tested with Wicket 6.19.0
In the Wicket guide: [Reading bundles with tag `<wicket:message>`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_reading_bundles_with_tag_wicket_message)